# Does this RegEx match the mentioned pattern

Tags: regex

I came up with this regular expression `(0|10)*` for some task. My friend is not convinced that this recognizes the string `0*100*`. (Please don't give me a Regular Expression to recognize this string. I know how to do it myself, but the regex I came up with is meant to solve some other problem in addition to recognizing this string). How many of you think it recognizes the string `0*100*`? I hope it does. To convince myself I tried to match the pattern with `grep` and it does match it. For example, the following command matches the pattern in the echo, which means my regex is correct. Is it not?

```
echo 00000000000000100000000000 | grep '\(0\|10\)*'
```

Comment: Assuming there really are asterisks in your string `0*100*`, your regex `(0|10)*` would only match up to the first 0...

Comment: You are right. Your pattern matches words over {0, 1} that do not have two consecutive ones, and end with zero (and the empty string). You may want `(0|10)*1?` to also include words that end with 1.

Comment: I'm not sure the question is appropriate for stack overflow, at least in the way you are asking it. Can you try something less subjective (not "How many of you think")? Do you have a specific problem.

Comment: @Kobi is that by any chance you who voted this question negative?

Comment: @Ragavan - On the contrary. I voted it up because I don't think it's that bad, just poorly worded. I can prove it by canceling the vote, if you'd like `:)`. (also, there are 3 people who down voted)

Answer (score 2):

It definitely matches. You are basically saying

> match a string where I have either 0 or 10 repeated any number of
>   times

Now take 0*100* and split it in groups:

1. 0* matches because it's 0 repeated any number of times.
2. 10 matches because it's 10 repeated one time.
3. 0* is the same as 1.

**Edit**: Let's also try a formal proof:

(0|10)* -> corresponding grammar:

```
A -> 0|10|e
B -> BA|AB
```

equivalent form:

```
A -> 0|10|e|0A|10A|A0|A10
```

0*100* -> corresponding grammar:

```
A -> 0|0A|A0|e
B -> 10
C -> ABA
```

equivalent form:

```
A -> 10|0A|A0
```

We can see that the second grammar's productions are a subset of the first grammar's productions, hence the first grammar should match any expression produced by the second grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it recognizes it in my opinion. 1 is not possible and 01 is not possible too. Your pattern cannot finish by 1 that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your expression does not match the entire pattern.  it matches a "10" in the middle of the pattern.  try `echo 00000000000000100000000000 | grep --color=always '(0\|10)*'` to see what part of the expression you are matching.  it would not match if you used `^(0\|10)*$` to force a match on the entire string.  I'm not sure if you were trying to match the entire string.  If you were using extended regular expressions (egrep or grep -E) it would match the entire string.  So it really matters exactly what flavor of regular expressions you are talking about.

Comment: Would it really not match the whole string? And if not, why not just the first `0`, or the first empty position? (I can't really check, unless there's an online tool. The VM would take too long to boot...)

Comment: try it with --color=auto or with the ^ and $ markers.  It matches the whole string with egrep, but not with grep (unless you send -E to grep).  It will match the 10 instead of the first 0 because 10 is longer (and its "maximal munch" by default)

Comment: Maximal match means starting on the first position, matching all zeros, 10, and all zeros. I did a quick test on http://www.online-utility.org/text/grep.jsp and http://www.regextester.com/,  and it does match the whole string.

Comment: Then that website is using something closer to the 'extended regular expressions' that are supported by grep -E instead of 'basic regular expressions' that are supported by grep without -E.  In basic regular expressions, ( and ) do not have the meaning you think they have.

Comment: Can you please explain what do they mean? I don't know grep too well... (also, I'm starting the Suse VM)

Comment: I added a pic of me running these commands here: http://i.imgur.com/BJOtS.png

Comment: I already tried on Suse, with `grep -o`. You are right, but you are not exactly correct, it isn't about length. `grep -o '(00000\|10)'*` also shows `10`. I obviously don't understand the syntax or something about grep... Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and by the way, the OP's pattern, `grep -o '\(0\|10\)*'`, does work - the backslashes where hidden behind poor formatting.

Comment: It depends where you test the pattern. For example in Java it matches the entire string.